# Query for Case Owner returns 0 results?

Tags: apex, query, list

I have a trigger passing cases to a class, excerpted below. 
The query for User matching caseowner.id returns zero results, though the query for user matching Salesperson__C (a custom lookup to a user) works.
Is it b/c an owner can be a queue?

```
for (Case OP: Cases){

            List <User> UsersToSub = new List <user>();
            List <User> CaseSalesperson = [select id from User where  id =: op.Salesperson__c ];
            List <User> CaseOwner = [select id from User where  id =: op.CreatedBy.id ];
            system.debug('owner=================== '+CaseOwner);

            UsersToSub.addAll(CaseOwner);
            UsersToSub.addAll(CaseSalesperson);
```

Note that this also returns zero results:

```
List <User> CaseOwner = [select id from User where  id =: op.CreatedBy.id ];
```

Comment: Why are you using op.createdby.id. You can use op.createdBy. It will return user id. Also for owner we have saperate field called 'Owner'. You can use that field rather using created By and yes there might be chance that Case owners are queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CreatedById` field instead of `CreatedBy.Id`.

See the [Default System Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Owner.id does not work, but OwnerId worked. As would CreatedbyId I imagine.

Comment: OwnerId can change, if the record owner changes. But CreatedById won't ever change. Keep that in mind in your implementation.

Comment: yes, i think keeping owners subscribed will be good